# replace nth field in the first row of CSV file

Tags: shell

I have a CSV file `test.csv` with data like 
`FHEAD,0000000001,STKU,20150927000000,201509270000000000,1153,,0000000801,W
FDETL,1,2,3
FDETL,9,7,4
FTAIL,2,3,4`

i wanted to replace `6th` filed of row starts with `FHEAD` to some derived value in the file `test.csv` And the resultant file content will look like
`cat test.csv
FHEAD,0000000001,STKU,20150927000000,201509270000000000,0000,,0000000801,W
FDETL,1,2,3
FDETL,9,7,4
FTAIL,2,3,4`

How can i do that in shell scripting.

Comment: Please show some expected output.

Comment: I have edited the request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }           # set delimiters
/^FHEAD/ {                           # if row starts with FHEAD
    $6="some derived value"          # replace 6th filed to some derived value
} 
1' file                              # output
FHEAD,0000000001,STKU,20150927000000,201509270000000000,some derived value,,0000000801,W
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed

```
sed '/^FHEAD/s/\(,[^,]*\)/,newvalue/5' infile
```